# Naming convention for an identity column in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, naming-conventions, database-schema

What is the point behind a naming convention when an identity column in a table is called like `UserID`, `ProductID` etc. instead of just an `ID`? What are the prons and cons?

Comment: Prefixing Identities with entity names increases readability of your schema and elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One advantage of longer names: when you use columns in complicated query with many tables (e.g. joins) you don't have to prefix columns to know from what table they come from and also you minimize problems with column names ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The same point *any* code convention has primarily: consistency. While it can be argued both pro and against the `Id` vs. `EntityId`, there is no clear winner. I wouldn't say that this is one of those [cases you need to pick a fight](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3179-you-only-get-one-chance-to-be-a-beginner) with... Is more important to stick to the rules of the org and keep the naming consistent.